# Python - Unsure why I am getting an TypError

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following piece of code to work out a percentage change using an sqlite3 cursor:

```
cursor3.execute('SELECT total FROM userTotals WHERE userid = :userid ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1', {'userid': userid})

for value in cursor3:
    total = value

percentageChange = ((float(valueList['Total']) - total)/abs(total))*100
```

In this case, there is no issue with float(valueList['Total']), and the total I am collecting from the database is of type REAL and the current value that sqlite command is returning is 1.0. Why do I get the following error?

```
    percentageChange = ((float(valueList['Total']) - total)/abs(total))*100
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: what does `total` hold? It seems to be a tuple.

Comment: Because, as the error message says, `total` is a tuple. (It's the same object as `value`, a row from your cursor.) You can't subtract a tuple from a number.

Comment: The values isn't `1.0`, rather, it is a tuple containing `1.0`, so `(1.0,)`

Comment: Database rows *are always sequences*, because you need to support 1 or more result columns. `value` is a tuple. Use `total, = cursor3.fetch_one()` to get just the one row and assign the single value to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query returns a bunch of rows. A row containing a single value is distinct from just that value (e.g. `1 != [1]`), so you need to extract the single field from it:

```
cursor3.execute('SELECT ... LIMIT 1', {'userid': userid})
total = cursor3.fetchone()[0]
```

Or:

```
cursor3.execute('SELECT ... LIMIT 1', {'userid': userid})
(total,) = cursor3.fetchone()

# total, = cursor3.fetchone() also works but it always looks funny to me
```

The above format works for results with multiple columns:

```
cursor3.execute('SELECT a, b ... LIMIT 1', {'userid': userid})
total1, total2 = cursor3.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your cursor is returning a tuple and value is referencing the tuple object.

You can confirm this by using a print statement like so:

```
for value in cursor3:
    print(value)
```

And examining what you are actually getting back.

Also, why not try using the following syntax:

```
for row in cursor3.execute('SELECT total FROM userTotals WHERE userid = :userid ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1', {'userid': userid}):
    your_formula_here
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `total` holds a value of type `tuple`. I would suggest you print the returned data from your query to see the actual contained data.
`print(cursor3)` or `print(value)` should do the trick.

You might need to separate two different two variables from cursor3. I expect it to be the data and query-related meta-data, such as the success state of the query or something similar. (Not sure about the last part though, without having tried it myself.)